# How to render data type html in template email magento2?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I have email template in Magento 2: **email-template.html**

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "%body" body=$data.body}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

But in variable `$data.body` is code html not text:

```
$data.body = `
<table width="100%"> 
  <tr> 
     <td>Name: </td> <td>Join Xanka </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> <td>Email: </td> <td>xanka@gmail.com</td> </tr>
  {{depend Test Send}} 
  <tr> <td>Subject: </td> <td>Test Send</td> </tr>
  {{/depend}} 
  <tr> <td>Message: </td> <td>we try send email use to test.</td> </tr>
</table>
```

So how to render code html when send send email. Many thank!

This is result when excuse code `print_r($this->_message->getBody());` in `sendMessage()` function:

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I change `{{trans "%body" body=$data.body}}` to `{{trans "%body" body=$data.body|raw}}`. it render success.

Answer (score 10):

Use `|raw` with your param variable.

example: `{{var data|raw}}`

where data is a param variable that passed to a template and contains a value which is HTML code. `data=<html code>`

Comment: thank you its very useful

Answer (score 6):

Along with `{{trans "%body" body=$data.body}}` to `{{trans "%body" body=$data.body|raw}}`.

Do remember to change `type="text"` to `type="html"` in `email_templates.xml`, otherwise you'll get plain HTML in your mails.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip type="html".  I just made a chilly mistake, It ruins around half an hour!