# Magento 2: How to remove HTML content from a custom email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I am having a custom module in which I created a custom email template where I am displaying the details of some the items and it's cost.

I am getting the details like,

```
//Details table rows as string
$dataDetails .= '<tr><td align="left" width="325"  style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;"><strong>' . $item['name'] . $this->getCustomOptionText($item) . '<br>sku: </strong>' . $item['sku']
 . '</td><td align="right" width="325"  style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">' . $formatedPrice
 . '</td><td align="right" width="325"  style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">' . $item['qty']
 . '</td><td align="right" width="325"  style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">' . $rowTotal . '</td></tr>';
    }

    //detail totals as a table in string
    $detail_footer = '<table>';

$detail_footer .= '<tr><td align="right" width="975" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >SubTotal : </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right" width="325" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >' . $formattedsubTotal . '</td></tr>';

    //Parametes the template email variable to send
    $params = array(
        'customer' => $customer,
        'shippingTitle' => $shippingTitle,
        'shippingAmount' => $shippingAmount,
        'grandTotal' => $grandTotal,
        'website' => $websiteName,
        'dataDetails' => $quoteDetails,
        'detail_footer' => $quote_footer,

    );
```

I am sending the email below as,

```
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($params);

    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

    try {
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('details_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                        ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($customerEmail, $customer)
                ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Sorry, we can\'t send the email right now.' . $e->getMessage()));
    }
```

In my email template, I am calling the data_datils as,

```
<tbody>
    {{trans "%dataDetails" dataDetails=$data.dataDetails}}
</tbody>
```

Here, I am receiving the email properly, however, the data_details received in the email is including the email tags.

In the email received the contents are like,

```
<table><tr><td align="right" width="975" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >SubTotal : </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right" width="325" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >$330.00</td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="975" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >Discount : </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right" width="325" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >$0.00</td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="975" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >Shipping & Delivery ( Flat Rate - Fixed ) : </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right" width="325" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" >$20.00</td></tr><tr><td align="right" width="975" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" ><strong>GrandTotal : </strong></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right" width="325" style="font-size:13px;padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;" ><strong>$350.00</strong></td></tr></table>
```

How can I exclude the HTML tags here and display only the values in the email?
I have searched for it but could not find anything relevant.

I also tried using trim but this also couldn't give me the proper result,

```
trim(strip_tags($dataDetails))
```

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: I will look into this in a couple of hours

Comment: @SwAt.Be Hello, did u get time to look into the issue?

Comment: I am sorry for the delay , i have a big deadline right now but i will get back to it tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the solution by referring to the link below:

[How to render data type html in template email magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/how-to-render-data-type-html-in-template-email-magento2)

Thus instead of clipping the HTML tags out, we could directly render HTML content in the email template.

We can use '|raw' with the param variable something like,

```
{{trans "%dataDetails" dataDetails=$data.dataDetails|raw}}
```