# Parse php plain text to html Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, html

I have a `string HTML` and have to convert(parse) it to HTML in PHP.

$stringHtml

[image]

How to convert this to HTML so that it all `<p>`, `<br>` tag works

this is Riskified decline email, and whatever content I add in its admin panel it prints as it is in email.
so I have added  `html_entity_decode` in $content

`code`

```
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('riskified_order_declined') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                    'store' => $order->getStoreId(),
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    "content" => html_entity_decode($content),
                    "subject" => $subject,
                ]
            )
            ->setFrom(
                [
                    "email" => $this->apiConfig->getDeclineNotificationSenderEmail(),
                    "name" => $this->apiConfig->getDeclineNotificationSenderName(),
                ]
            )
            ->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getCustomerName())
            ->getTransport();
```

This is what my email looks like. no formatting it just prints the

tag.

[image]

Riskfied email_template.xml

```
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template
        id="riskified_order_declined"
        label="Notification sent to customer when order was declined"
        file="order/declined.html"
        type="html"
        module="Riskified_Decider"
        area="frontend"
/>
```

`declined.html`

```
<!--@subject {{var subject}} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
{{var content}}
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure these points below are set up:

1. Change type="text" to type="html" in email_templates.xml, otherwise you'll get plain HTML in your mails.
2. Render the $content in the email using this format **{{var content|raw}}**

Reference post: [How to render data type html in template email magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/how-to-render-data-type-html-in-template-email-magento2)

Comment: Tam its already html <config
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template
            id="riskified_order_declined"
            label="Notification sent to customer when order was declined"
            file="order/declined.html"
            type="html"
            module="Riskified_Decider"
            area="frontend"
    />
</config>

Comment: @summu can you add your email template content here?

Comment: added see updated question

Comment: @summu sorry, I mean the content of this file order/declined.html

Comment: Tam updated in question

Comment: @summu Can you update {{var content}} to  {{var content|raw}} and then retry?

Comment: So i dont need to do html_entity_decode($content) ?

Comment: Yes, no need to do html_entity_decode($content)

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: @Toam wait, I need to time to test that, as my riskified is only configured to staging only and so I need my pull request to get it merged in staging and then run cron job in parallel for Adyen payments

Comment: If it works, please accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject these below classes in your construct. Add below code in your construct :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
 */
protected $filterProvider;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider  [description]
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager    [description]
 */
public function __construct(
    .......
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    .......
) {
    .......
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    .......
}

/**
 * Return filter html data
 *
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
 */
public function getCmsFilterContent($contentData)
{
    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    return $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($contentData);
}
```

Now, call function `getCmsFilterContent()` in your phml file and pass html content varible in `getCmsFilterContent()` function as arguement.

or if you want to change in email template then, you need to use **'|raw'** with your param variable.

**example: '{{var data|raw}}'**

**Hope, it will helpful for you.**

Comment: thanks your answer helped too

Answer (score 0):

basically, it should work without any issue if you just write

```
echo $stringHtml;
```

Please send me your screenshot if you are seeing no tags while echoing.

Comment: I know that but this is riskified decline email, and whatever content i add in its admin panel it prints as it is in email, see my updated question

Comment: If you are using html_entity_decode then try inserting your "<",">" signs as "&lt;" and "&gt;" once, where html_entity_decode will convert it into proper signs.