# Magento 2 - Custom Variable | How to get the Plain Value as well as HTML value using directive {{CustomVar code="CUSTOM_VAR_CODE"}} in CMS Blocks?

Tags: magento2, cms-block, magento2.3.3, template-directive, custom-variable

I have added the Custom Variable from Admin > System > Other settings > Custom Variables >  Add New Variable, it is possible to add both the Variable HTML Value as well as Variable Plain Value as in the screen shot below

[image]

When using the directive {{CustomVar code="CUSTOM_VAR_CODE"}} in Content > Static > Blocks it always retrieves the Variable HTML Value, but there is no way or documentation on how to retrieve the Plain Value using directive {{CustomVar code="CUSTOM_VAR_CODE"}} ?

Please share thoughts

Comment: Have you seen the answers here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/how-to-render-data-type-html-in-template-email-magento2

Comment: @DominicXigen the solution / answer shared in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/how-to-render-data-type-html-in-template-email-magento2 seems to translate the string, I did tried the solution but it didnot work as expected.

In my case I am adding the HTML value as well as Plain value in the fields as in the screen shot in my original question while creating the custom variable, I am looking a way to get the Plain value as by default the directive  {{CustomVar code="CUSTOM_VAR_CODE"}} gives HTML value only....